# Name equivalence question

Tags: c, equivalence, type-equivalence

Suppose I have:

```
int a;
int b;
```

Are the variables `a` and `b` name equivalent (more specifically, since primitive types don't have type names, can they be considered name equivalent)?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about C.  I just added a tag for C for you :)

Comment: your question doesn't make sense...

Comment: What about it does not make sense?  Do you know what name equivalence is?

Comment: Yes I do, but you are also mixing in type-equivelence...

Comment: Name equivalence is one method for asserting type-equivalence.

Comment: Exactly, and you have have type and name equivalence because you have the same exact type, you have aliased them or anything.

Comment: What do you mean by, "you have type and name equivalence"?

Comment: According to the answer I posted, the code in my question does not exhibit name equivalence (and thus, doesn't exhibit type equivalence).

Comment: @Nix Your comments make even less sense (and aren't grammatical). There are two kinds of type equivalence: structural equivalence and name equivalence. variables of type "int" are name equivalent because they have the same type by name.

Comment: Part of the confusion here is that name equivalence and structural equivalence are normally considered attributes of _type systems_, not individual values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Name (more properly, nominal) equivalence means that the values have the same type as determined by the (fully qualified) name of their type -- for instance, `a` and `b` are nominally type equivalent because they both have "int" type. Structural equivalence means that the values are considered to have the same type because their types are structurally equivalent, regardless of the name. Nominal type equivalence implies structural type equivalence since a named type is structurally equivalent to itself. Your `a` and `b`, are nominally type equivalent because they have the same type by name ("int"). The claim that "primitive types don't have type names" is simply false -- `int` is a type name. And there is no difference between `int a; int b;` and `int a, b;` -- both define `a` and `b` with the same (structurally and by name) type.

C's type system is generally by name ... e.g., `int *` and `short*` are  different types even if `int` and `short` have the same representation, and `struct foo { int x; }` and `struct bar { int x; }` are different types even though they always have the same representation.

Comment: I'll accept this and assume the professor was wrong.  Past test answers from the class indicate that you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Some class notes I found seem to indicate that with:

```
int a;
int b;
```

Variables `a` and `b` **are not** name equivalent.

However, with:

```
int a, b;
```

Variables `a` and `b` **are** name equivalent.

Comment: Either those class notes or your interpretation of them is quite wrong -- what possible sense or value could be had from such a distinction? In both cases, `a` and `b` have the same type (namely "int") so of course they are type equivalent, and the sort of type equivalence is name equivalence -- C considers `a` and `b` the same type, and thus no casts or promotions are necessary for operations between them, precisely because they have the same type by name -- "int". OTOH, if one of them were declared to be "short", they would have different types even if "int" and "short" are the same size.

Answer (score -1):

C adopts structural equivalence except for structures and unions; for these types, name equivalence is used. It is true that the values have the same type as determined by the name of their type in name equivalence and that the values are considered to have the same type as determined by structurally equivalent in structural equivalence. But even in structural equivalence, it is not determined regardless of the name.

Basically, atomic types in a programming language have names and they are used both in name equivalence and structural equivalence. The difference comes from derived types such as `int *` or `char[10]`. It is true that "primitive types have type names." And C's type system is comparing the structure of derived types up to user-defined names excluding type synonyms even they are defined by the user using `typedef`.

C's type system is generally adopting structural equivalence. For instance, `int *` and `short *` are different types but `int *` and `int *` are the same types even though no names are attributed to the pointers. The reason for that `struct foo { int x; }` and `struct bar { int x; }` are different types is because they have different structure up to user-defined type names. Types `struct foo *` and `struct foo *` are the same types since they have the same structure. Note that `struct` defines not only the structure but also name, more precisely structure tag name, of the type.

Simply, in structural equivalence, the types are unfolded up to atomic type names and they are compared. In C, the types are unfolded up to names including user-defined names by `struct` or `union`. (For unfolding, please refer http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/TypeChecking.html/node3.html) This is the difference. Naturally, name equivalent types are structurally equivalent, but not the converse.

For the following case:

```
int x;
int y;
```

`x` and `y` and both name equivalent and structural equivalent. But, in the following case:

```
int *x;
int *y;
```

`x` and `y` are structural equivalent but not name equivalent. Even for the following case:

```
int *x, *y;
```

`x` and `y` are not considered equivalent in a strict name equivalence scheme, for this declaration is considered as just a shorthand of the previous declaration. Ada is a well-known language adopting the strict name equivalence.